# Conditional TabStrip in Telerik MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-mvc

I need to implement conditional TabStrip in Telerik MVC Grid. The parent grid row contains the cell value of Status. If the status is Active i dont suppose to show the tabstrip in the child grid. If the status is Pending, then i need to show the TabStrip to create new item.

I have to do something like this:

```
if ("<#= Status #>" == "Pending") // The condition is not working here. Always show this tab.
                    {
                        items.Add().Text("Create New Detail").Url("/Acq/PoDet/Create/<#=Id#>");
                    }
                })
                .ToHtmlString()
```

Comment: Late to the party here, but I am looking for something very similar. Did you ever get a solution to the above?

Answer (score 0):

Since most probably you are using Ajax binding you will need to write a little bit of JavaScript to achieve your goal. Your writings are not correct because you are meshing JavaScript code (#= ...#) with C# code.
Here is what an idea what you can do in the detail template, (it is a little bit tricky because you need to escape the special symbols):

```
<script id="employeesTemplate" type="text/kendo-tmpl">

            @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
                .Name("test#=EmployeeID#")
                .Items(it=>it.Add().Text("test").Content("content test"))
                .ToClientTemplate()
                    )


           <script>
                    if (#=EmployeeID # % 2) {  
                        $('\#test' + #=EmployeeID#).data().kendoTabStrip.append({"text":"This is the TabTitle",content:"this is some content"})
                    }
           <\/script>



</script>
```

The example above is using the client API method called append to append a node to the TabStrip on the client side when the DetailView is generated into the detail row if the `EmployeeID%2 == 0` (a simple condition).

I hope you got the idea.

Comment: Its not working. Showing syntax error within Teleik grid. Really i dont get your logic.